# R - Detecting expressions

Tags: r

What type of object is passed to `myFunc` as x?  It doesn't seem to be an expression, nor a function and str just evaluates it.  I understand that I can use `force()` to evaluate.  I'm wondering if there's some way to gather more information about x without evaluating it.

```
myFunc = function( x )
{
    is.expression( x )    
    is.function( x )
    str( x )
}
myFunc( { x = 5; print( x + 1 ) } )
```

Comment: doesn't seem to report it as an expression.  neither does type() nor mode()

Comment: I think you might be getting confused between expressions (which are basically lists of unevaluated call) and the results of an expression.  `x` in your function is 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `match.call` for extracting the arguments:

```
myFunc <- function( x ) {
    x <- match.call()$x
    print(class(x))
    print(typeof(x))
    print(mode(x))
    print(storage.mode(x))
    print(is.expression(x))
    print(is.call(x))
    if (is.call(x)) print(x[[1]])
}
myFunc({x = 5; print("a")})
myFunc(expression(x))
x <- factor(1)
myFunc(x)
myFunc(1)
```

Probably I need to say that `{` is a function in R, so `{...}` is no more than `call`.

*Updated*: why `x` is not `function` while `{` is `function`:

```
f <- function(x) {
    x <- match.call()$x
    print(eval(x[[1]]))
    print(is.function(eval(x[[1]])))
}

f({1})
```

Comment: thanks for putting this together!  If { is a function, then why does is.function(x) return FALSE?  Is there a way to change the environment of x?

Comment: because x is `call`, not `function`. `call` consists of `function` and `arguments`. See also update.

Answer (score 2):

I think `class` would do the trick... See [docs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/class.html).

EDIT: According to the [docs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Paren.html),

> for {, the result of the last expression evaluated

Which means the class is the class resulting from the evaluation, which is why it not showing up as an "expression". It is being passed after evaluation.

Comment: Hmmm, `class` returns `numeric` which makes me think it actually evaluates the expression before testing it...

Comment: Actually, even if you try to assign that expression to a variable, the expression is immediatly run, and you end up with a numeric variable containing 6...

Comment: Exactly. The evaluation is performed immediately, prior to assignment or passing the result to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Dason just posted a similar response to this on [Talkstats.com](http://www.talkstats.com/) for determining if an object is a data frame or a list ([click here for a link to that post)](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/22305-Merging-Multiple-Data-Frames).  I just extended it to an expression which I think suits your needs.

```
j.list <- function(list, by = NULL){
    print("list")
    print(list)
}

j.data.frame <- function(df, ..., by = NULL){
    print("data frame")
    print(df)
}


j.expression <- function(expression, by = NULL){
    print("expression")
    print(expression)
}

j <- function(x, ...){
    UseMethod("j")
}

j(list(test = "this is a list"))
j(data.frame(test = 1:10))
j(expression(1+ 0:9))
```

Comment: j( { x = 5; print( x + 1 ) } ) throws error "no applicable method for 'j' applied to object of class "c('double','numeric')"  but the solution seemed clever =)

Comment: It wasn't necessarily to determine if something was a data frame or a list - it was to tailor the function call to whether the argument was a data frame or a list since the poster wanted to be able to offer similar functionality for both cases but wanted the function to tell if the object being passed in was a list or data frame. But thanks for the shoutout.